# how to handle multiple requests using python flask

Tags: python, flask

I have a python flask service to do ssh and run some commands on a router that will take 5 seconds for each request. 
So now if I give two requests at a time 1st request I'm getting the response in 5 seconds but the second it's taking 10 seconds so the code is responding sequentially.
How do I handle 100 requests coming at the same time and respond to each request in 5 seconds?

Comment: You need to run your Flask app behind a WSGI service which will then employ multiprocessing/multithreading to call your Flask app separately for each request. Start by reading about [**Flask Deployment Options**](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/deploying/#deployment-options).

Comment: @zwer that's actually the answer

Comment: unfortunately, I was using Connexions Framework somewhat similar to that of flask. and I tried this threaded = True it didn't work.

Comment: No, it is not. anyhow, thanks for the suggestion.